# How to use pkg with puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, http, https, puppeteer

I've been trying to make this simple code work with pkg.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scraper(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const title = await page.title();
  await browser.close();
  return title;
}

scraper("http://example.com").then(console.log);
```

But the exe closed at once.

I Know that the problem is that there is no "specified" path for chromium. I searched a lot and tried a lot of different things but nothing worked.

Something I tried:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/path/to/Chrome'});
```

But it never worked as well.